# Jquery - wrapping a element inside a div as you scroll down and unwrapping as you scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've figured out how to wrap an element inside a div using jquery.
However, I would like to wrap it inside the div as you scroll down and unwrap it as you scroll up.

Is it doable?

I've already figured out to wrap it scrolling down. But I think there's flaw in the logic as the wrapping just keep be executed as I scroll down. It should only be executed once after I scroll pass 500px.

thanks!

```
<script>


$(function() {
//caches a jQuery object containing the header element
var header = $(".show-on-scroll-wrapper");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
          $('.mobile-nav-toggle-label').wrapAll('<div id="showOnScrollWrapper" class="show-on-scroll-wrapper show"></div>'); 
        //the wrapping should only happen once 
    } else {
        //needs to be able unwrap the div if I scroll back to the top
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You could store a reference to the wrapping object and only wrap it if the reference is null.  And then for the else you could simply replace with the reference with it's contents:

```
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var $showOnScrollWrapper = null;
    var header = $(".show-on-scroll-wrapper");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 500) {
        if (null === $showOnScroll) {
            $showOnScrollWrapper = $('<div id="showOnScrollWrapper" class="show-on-scroll-wrapper show"></div>');
            $('.mobile-nav-toggle-label').wrapAll($showOnScrollWrapper); 
        }
    } else if ($showOnScrollWrapper !== null) {
        $showOnScrollWrapper.replaceWith($showOnScrollWrapper.html());
        $showOnScrollWrapper = null;
    }
});
```